# ID this plane with a white body and a blue stripe

Tags: aircraft-identification

Going through my Dad's things I found this plane and would love to know what it is.

[image]

Comment: I hope your father wasn't on board for that particular landing - it looks like that one may have been a bit rough!

Comment: Any idea where the picture was taken?

Comment: I think it was around Terrace, BC

Answer (score 24):

To add to Tevildo's answer, the livery for the Scottish Aviation Twin Pioneer appears to be this one

[image: Scottish Aviation Twin Pioneer]

from [here](https://www.aerialvisuals.ca/AirframePhotoViewer.php?Serial=39174) which per [this](https://www.aerialvisuals.ca/AirframeDossier.php?Serial=16752) seems to have been leased to Dampier Mining Company; that picture was taken somewhere near Sydney Australia. I suspect there aren't many of these planes so it might be possible to get to an actual airframe.

Following up on harshbutfair's detective skills in their answer, it looks like it might be C-GNIS. Here's a picture of C-GNIS. [This](https://www.goodall.com.au/australian-aviation/twin-pioneer/twinpioneer.html) page (search for C-GNIS) details its history. At some stage it was indeed parked and vandalized.

[image: C-GNIS]

Apparently it was then restored (perhaps by the OP's father?) and at least [recently](https://www.silverhawkauthor.com/post/canadian-warplanes-1-british-columbia) was at the Quesnel Heritage Aircraft Museum in BC Canada.

Quesnel Heritage Aircraft Museum, Quesnel Airport, PO Box 52, Richard Store, Quesnel, British Columbia, V2] 5E5. Tel: 250-747-2542 - if you want to visit it!

Comment: The paint sure looks the same, just the name scratched off maybe.

Comment: @Sunny I think harshbutfair found the registration and I found a picture and a history of it :-)

Comment: Yes, that is the very plane.  My Dad was part of the group that pulled it out of the bush and brought it to Quesnel.  My thanks to all of you!

Comment: @Sunny If you're happy with one of the answers you've received, you can accept it by clicking on the "tick" icon.

Comment: I have not used this type of forum before. What is a tick icon?  The triangle?  thank you, :)

Answer (score 21):

It looks very much like a [Scottish Aviation Twin Pioneer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scottish_Aviation_Twin_Pioneer).  The stub "wings" from the lower fuselage to the undercarriage are quite distinctive.
[image: Image from RuthAS, via Wikipedia]
Image from RuthAS, via Wikipedia.

Comment: Thank you very much!  My Dad was part of the recovery team that salvaged the aircraft.  Sadly I don't know what became of it.

Answer (score 17):

You can almost make out the registration on the left side of the image. It looks like it starts with C- followed by a G, and then ending in an S. From searching for Scottish Aviation on [Aviation History Canada](https://aviationhistorycanada.ca/registerh) I believe it could be C-GNIS.

Comment: I think we have a winner. Also see https://www.goodall.com.au/australian-aviation/twin-pioneer/twinpioneer.html which lists the history of C-GNIS (search for it). Upvoted. I might stick the pictures in my answer!